# What is an equivalent to database_cleaner in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a spec, with an object and two contexts. In one context I set one key to nil and in the other not:

```
describe SomeClass::SomeService, type: :model do
  describe '#some_method' do

    subject { described_class.new(params, current_user).some_method }
    mocked_params = {
      min_price: 0,
      max_price: 100
    }

    let(:params) { mocked_params }
    let(:current_user) { User.create(email: 'name@mail.com') }

    context 'with invalid params' do
      it 'returns nil if any param is nil' do
        params[:min_price] = nil
        expect(subject).to eq(nil)
      end
    end

    context 'with valid params' do
      it 'returns filtered objects' do
        expect(subject).to eq([])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that the second test  fails because `min_price` is still nil.

1. I read that from Rails 5 on I don't need `database_cleaner`. Do I need it or not?
2. I thought that the `let` method creates a new object every time it sees the variable. Since I have two contexts, and the `subject` method is called in both of them, and inside the `subject` I have the variable `params`, why is the `params` object not a new one with all the fields at every context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read that from rails 5 on I don't need database_cleaner. Do I need
>   or not?

No. It's no longer needed. In previous versions of Rails the database transaction method of rolling back changes only worked (at times) with TestUnit/Minitest and fixtures.

> I thought that the let method creates a new object every time it sees
>   the variable. Since I have two context, and the subject method is
>   called in both of them, and inside the subject I have the variable
>   params, why the params object is not a new one at every context? (with
>   all the fields)

This is completely wrong.

> Use let to define a memoized helper method. The value will be cached
>   across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples.

When you do:

```
mocked_params = {
  min_price: 0,
  max_price: 100
}

let(:params) { mocked_params }
```

You're really just returning a reference to the object `mocked_params` and then mutating that object.

If you do:

```
let(:params) do 
 {
    min_price: 0,
    max_price: 100
  }
end
```

You will get a new hash object on the first call to `let` and the value will then be cached but not shared between examples. But that's really the tip of the iceberg with this spec.

```
describe SomeClass::SomeService, type: :model do
  describe '#some_method' do
    let(:current_user) { User.create(email: 'name@mail.com') }
    # explicit use of subject is a serious code smell!
    let(:service) { described_class.new(params, current_user) }

    context 'with invalid params' do
      # since let is lazy loading we can define it in this context instead
      let(:params) do
        {
          min_price: nil,
          max_price: 100
        }
      end

      it 'returns nil if any param is nil' do
        # actually call the method under test instead of misusing subject
        # this makes it much clearer to readers what you are actually testing
        expect(service.some_method).to eq(nil)
      end
    end

    context 'with valid params' do
      let(:params) do
        {
          min_price: 0,
          max_price: 100
        }
      end

      it 'returns filtered objects' do
        expect(service.some_method).to eq([])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Its also pretty questionable why the object under test takes a hash as the first positional parameter and not as the last parameter which is the Ruby way.

Comment: Thanks for all the theoretical input: '# explicit use of subject is a serious code smell!' Why it was so wrong my use of subject?

Comment: Because the readability of the test is seriously impacted. See http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/ - yeah its old and the code is outdated but the general point still stands.

Comment: what do you think about let(:some_method), so that I don't have to use multiple times expect(service.some_method)?

Comment: Does it improve the readiblity of the spec? No. Does it DRY it significantly? No.

Comment: Of course this depends on the exact use case. Is the method under test being called with slight different arguments in each spec? - No. Is it being called with the same arguments repeatedly and the arguments are lengthy? - Yes. Is it worth the added complexity? I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you initialize the `mocked_params` only once when the file is loaded and then you change that hash in the first test.

Instead create the params within the `let` block which would lead to a re-creation of the hash for each test.

Change

```
mocked_params = {
  min_price: 0,
  max_price: 100
}

let(:params) { mocked_params }
```

to

```
let(:params) do
  {
    min_price: 0,
    max_price: 100
  }
end
```

Comment: I understand the issue and the solution, but what if I wanted to have the mocked_params outside of the let declaration, just to have a clean code. Is not possible?

Comment: What would be possible too, but then you need to duplicate or clone the hash before using `let(:params) { mocked_params.dup }`. Btw I would argue that your version is more verbose and therefore not clean.